# Comparing means using t test and plot it using ggplot

Tags: ggplot2, t-test

I have the following data frame:

```
species <- c("Species1", "Species1", "Species2", "Species2", "Species3", "Species3", "Species4", "Species4", "Species5", "Species5", "Species6", "Species6")

# Create the campaign vector
campaign <- rep(c(1, 2), times = 6)

# Create random values for mean and sd
set.seed(1)  # Set seed for reproducibility
mean_values <- runif(12, min = 0, max = 10)
sd_values <- runif(12, min = 0, max = 2)

# Create the data frame
df <- data.frame(species, campaign, mean = mean_values, sd = sd_values)
```

Now I plotted the means +- sd for each species (x-Axis) and for both campaigns colored differently. Next, I would like to perform a t-test to see if there is a significant difference between the means of campaign 1 and 2 for each species. How can I do this and plot the result into the ggplot?